# How to remove rear window glue

Tags: car, repair, window

My rear window brokw, shattered into about a million pieces.
The only parts left, were stuck where the window was glued to the rear hatch of the car.

I'm getting a new window installed soon, so I want to make it as easy as possible to install the new one.
To that end, I wish to remove the glue leftovers.

Anyone got a tip on how to get rid of it, without damaging the plastic underneath?

Here's a picture of the glue in question. It feels like dense rubber, although a tiny bit foamy.
[image]

Comment: If a professional repairer is installing the new window, don't bother. They will have the correct chemicals to remove the old adhesive. If it is urethane, there isn't any "easy" way to clean it up and any mistakes you make *will* cause damage (and at worst, leave you with a replacement window that leaks where it isn't properly glued down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to clean it is with a blade, as in a razor blade. Use it cutting sideways into the glue, not as a scraper. This will cut away the excess glue. Then, using a heat gun, you can soften what's left of the glue and clean it off with a putty knife. Just be careful around trim just inside the window area, as well as any fascia on the outside which buts up to where the window is at.